# a member that is computed or generated cannot be changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a column in database that takes a bit value(1,0). the default is set to 1. I am using Linq. when I try to change the value it gives me this exception.

```
  A member that is computed or generated cannot be changed.
```

in Linq

```
  [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_IsDefault", DbType="Bit NOT NULL",IsDbGenerated="true" )]
```

if I remove the IsDbGenerated Attribute. I am able to change the values but when I import some data directly using a CSV file then the default value is always coming 0 but it was set to 1 in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you set the default value of the field or property in code to 1 (or true) as well?  You could also set the default in the constructor of the object that the field belongs to.